# react-final-form: how to submit per change in fields without button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I have a text field, dropdown, date picker, and etc. My form won't have a save button so I don't have any type of "submit". For text field, I want the onSubmit to trigger to happen when the user enters enter button. For dropdown and date picker, it would call onSubmit when a user picks a different value aka onChange. It seems like you need a button or something of type submit to trigger onSubmit but it's not like I can put two types per Field. Any ideas on how I can trigger submit per field without any clicking any buttons?

here is a sandbox where I tried to trigger onSubmit per field.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-external-submit-button-forked-gz40r3

Answer (score 0):

one of the parameters that is getting passed in the Form's render is a reference to "form". You can trigger form.submit() in onChange or pass it as a param to another function and call it within that function.